# Log transform all DVs for multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation

Hello brainier folk than me,

I'm looking to perform a multiple hierarchal regression and considering log transforming at least one IV which is the main one of interest to improve linearity. Should I therefore attempt to transform all of the IVs?

Comment: Why would you want to transform the variables?

Comment: Hi Tim, exactly my question! Is it okay to have a mix of log transformed and non transformed IVs in the regression?

Comment: But why are you transforming them? No reason why having some of the variables transformed and some not would be a problem.